# Angular-Snap not functioning

Tags: angularjs, snap.js

Folks,

I am trying to include angular-snap in my project but for some reason it is not functioning as it should.

I have created a plunkr  for the same:
http://plnkr.co/edit/sLV087z27H2bpJDm1XIJ

For those who are familiar with angular-snap.. kindly advice what I am missing here ?

Comment: How are you expecting it to function in your Plunker?

Comment: The string "I'm a left drawer!" should not be displayed by default. It should only get displayed when I pull the left edge of the page towards right. I am basically trying to replicate this DEMO http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be a bug with `<snap-content>` as an element.  [This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OrvxGigOHP0adqVR3e9E) works as advertised.

I forked your plunker so everything should be the same.  The only change I made was to replace the markup with this:

```
<snap-drawer>
  <div>I should be hidden</div>
</snap-drawer>

<div snap-content>Hello! I'm your main content!</div>
```

Comment: The elements inside snap-drawer as not hidden by default.. I believe they should be. Would you know how to achieve this ?

Comment: By looking at the example, it seems that the 2 divs are absolutely positioned on top of one another.  So if you have a background color to both, the one underneath should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this trying to find angular-snap since it's disappeared from GitHub. Thanks for the copy I'll grab from the Plunkr.

Your issue appears to be an accidentally closed `div`?

`<div snap-drawer id="shelf-1"></div>`

Removing the `</div>` on that line left it working normally. Your IDE may have plunked that in without you noticing.